# How can I access a rdp remote application on linux?

Tags: opensuse, xrdp, rdp

I have a webfeed url for a rdp remote application, served on a remote windows machine.

If I was on a windows OS, I could just go to the control panel and there would be an option there (as shown on this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Enterprise-Mobility-Security/Introducing-RemoteApp-and-Desktop-Connections/ba-p/246803)).

However, I have a linux OS (OpenSuse Tumbleweed). Do any of you, know a way for me to install/access these applications with my OS?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

- https://software.opensuse.org/package/rdesktop
- https://software.opensuse.org/package/remmina
- https://software.opensuse.org/package/freerdp

Those should allow you a connection to RDP.